# new user powershell get-service

Tags: powershell, loops, user-input, ping

What is wrong with this code?

```
Clear-Host

$num1 = Read-Host "Please choose"

1 = service
2 = process
3 = pinging
4 = multiplying a number

$num1 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for service "
Snumber = 1
Get-Service

$num2 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for process"
$Number = 2
Get-Process

$num3 = Read-Host " Please enter a number to ping"
$Number = 3
$ComputerName = Read-Host "enter the FQDN of the target computer"
Test-Connection $ComputerName FQDN

$num4 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for double the number"
$Number = 4
$num4 = Read-Host "Pleas enter number 5" 
Write_Host "Your original number was 5, now it's 10"`enter code here`
```

why is the script not respecting the user choice?
why is it looping?
The script is not pinging.
 I want the user to choose one number then the task is completed and the cursor is back to the question please choose a number? so on
I don't want it to go to the next question after it complete the task

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: If it is for a homework task, please remember to complete full Harvard style citations and referencing for the assistance provided. You are sure to get extra marks.

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong with your code block so I just re-wrote 90% of it with what I believe you are trying to accomplish.

```
# Sets up the visual choices for the user
Function Choose-Selection {
    Clear-Host

    Write-Host "1: Service"
    Write-Host "2: Process"
    Write-Host "3: Pinging"
    Write-Host "4: Multiplying a number"
    Write-Host "Q: Quit" -ForegroundColor Red 
}

# Displays those choices
Choose-Selection
# Enters loop
Do{
    # Checks for a selection from the user
    $selection = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
    # Switches take the input from the user and runs code based on the switch
    Switch($selection) {
        '1' {
            $num1 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for service"
            (Get-Service)[$num1]
            Sleep -Seconds 5
            Choose-Selection
        } '2' {
            $num2 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for process"
            (Get-Process)[$num2]
            Choose-Selection
        } '3' {
            $ComputerName = Read-Host "enter the FQDN of the target computer"
            Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName
            Sleep -Seconds 5
            Choose-Selection
        } '4' {
            $num4 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for double the number"
            # Checks to see if input is an int. If not an int, terminates script
            If($num4 -match '^[0-9]+$') {
                "Your original number was $num4, now it's $([int]$num4*2)"
            } Else {
                Throw "You have not entered a valid number. Menu terminated."
            }
            Sleep -Seconds 5
            Choose-Selection
        } 'q'  { 

            'Leaving Menu...'
            Return
        }
    }
 }

Until($response -eq 'Q')
```

Your problems as I see them.

```
# This section does nothing except cause errors
1 = service
2 = process
3 = pinging
4 = multiplying a number

# What is SNumber? Variables need a $ in front of them
$num1 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for service "
Snumber = 1
# What are you doing with the number they give you? You are retrieving all services
Get-Service

$num2 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for process"
$Number = 2
# What are you doing with the number they give you? You are retrieving all Processed
Get-Process

$num3 = Read-Host " Please enter a number to ping"
# What is this variable used for?
$Number = 3
$ComputerName = Read-Host "enter the FQDN of the target computer"
Test-Connection $ComputerName FQDN

$num4 = Read-Host " Please enter a number for double the number"
# What is this variable used for?
$Number = 4
$num4 = Read-Host "Pleas enter number 5" 
# What if I chose the number 200, it will still say I chose 5
# Well it would if it didn't error out. The command is Write-Host
Write_Host "Your original number was 5, now it's 10"`enter code here`
```

Comment: i am learning powershell and i really appreciate the explication. i am still confuse about the cmdlets thank

Comment: Thank You bothDrew i like the way you put the questions it helped me understand better the logic behind it.